# left of '->C' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

this file contains only the declaration of this class.

## Test.h

```
class Test
    {
    private:
        Types::A a;
        B bb; // B stands for class B { // some objects;};
        C cc; // C "
        D dd; // D "
        CString str;
    public:
        Test();

        void getADetails();
        int getBDetails();
        void getCDetails();
        void getDDetails();

    };
```

This file contains the definition of all the APIs.

## Test.cpp

Here in the constr, we are using member initialiser for the object bb

```
    Test::Test() :bb(Log) // bb constr expects a static log func, all other constrs doesn't contain any parameters 
    {

    }
    int Test::getCDetails()
    {
        this->cc.getDetails(this->str, this->A);
        return 0;
    }
```

This file contains the Testcases to create an object of that class.

## TestCase.cpp

```
    TEST_METHOD(test_App)
    {
        Test t;
        t.getCDetails();
        t.getBDetails();
    }
```

When  i am trying to compile the code, it is giving compile time errors.Please c the trace below:

> Error 26  error C2227: left of '->B' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
>   Error   28  error C2227: left of '->C' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Could anyone please explain as i am new to c++.

Comment: please fix the formatting. It is impossible to read it.

Comment: `TEST_METHOD(z)` are you using some evil macro here, or what is this? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `B` and `C` are types , if you want to use the variable use `->bb` or `->cc`

Comment: Done.Please go through it now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the member variables (via `this`), not the types.

Like this:

```
this->aa
this->bb
this->cc
```

Also, `this` is not *necessary* in your case.

Comment: Used the above only, typing mistake.

Comment: the problem here is this pointer is pointing to null(came to know this when searched for this error ..source msdn).But reason is why??

Comment: @varun That's not at all what the msdn doc says for [C2227](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z8wd049.aspx)

Comment: ok.Could you please tell me why m i getting this error.